# SQL injection on Activerecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I currently have this:

```
products = Product.select("DISTINCT(products.id), products.*").joins("JOIN (SELECT * FROM `shop_categorizations` WHERE (shop_categorizations.shop_category_id IN (SELECT id FROM `shop_categories` WHERE (`shop_categories`.shop_id = #{id} AND (`shop_categories.id` IN (#{shop_categories})))))) AS `shop_categorizations` ON `shop_categorizations`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`");
```

I was thinking that this query would be susceptible to sql injection. How would I make this query safe from it. I assume binding but I don't know how to apply it here.

A background on the models if it helps:

```
Product belongs to ShopCategory
ShopCategory belongs to Shop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I think you don't need binding. Both the parameters are Fixnum, you can just convert the input to Fixnum to guard against SQL injection:

> JOIN (SELECT * FROM `shop_categorizations` WHERE
>   (shop_categorizations.shop_category_id IN (SELECT id FROM
>   `shop_categories` WHERE (`shop_categories`.shop_id = #{**id.to_i**}
>   AND (`shop_categories.id` IN (#{**shop_categories.map(&:to_i)**}))))))
>   AS `shop_categorizations` ON `shop_categorizations`.`product_id` =
>   `products`.`id`

If you really need to handle string data types, you can prevent SQL injection by escaping/quoting it, see:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote